# web application for collaborative work

Tags: project-management, collaboration

i´m lookin for a web based collaborative work plataform for people in differents countries. They need to share word, ppt, images and videos and maybe an online edition tool and forum system or something like that.

wiki <- not usefull: it´s all public (The need private data)
moodle <- we have to install and administrate it. Not good we want to be free of any software administration

any other ideas?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basecamp? http://basecamphq.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://www.assembla.com/

I've used them to collaborate with a team in a different city. They have:

- private wiki
- private source control (svn and mercurial afaik)
- calendars/project management
- issue tracking

Basically everything you need for a software project.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you to look into: [MindTouch](http://www.mindtouch.com)

The developer site http://developer.mindtouch.com/ uses public pages, but you can always make sure that project pages are PRIVATE and still share article content with other invited users.

And you can see forums used with the software here: [www.completeguides.net/01_The_Complete_Android_Guide/Android_Answers](http://www.completeguides.net/01_The_Complete_Android_Guide/Android_Answers)